# bug in coin slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have used coin slider which is extracted from this site http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/. It is now auto scrolling and shows previous and next only on hover. I need to disable the auto scroll and show the previous and next buttons normally too. The internal script that i have used is

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#games').coinslider({ hoverPause: false });
        $('#games1').coinslider({ hoverPause: false });

    });
</script>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for next an prev buttons use this

```
cs-navigation-games {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: It's working fine. The previous and next buttons shows normally.Thanks. But how can i stop the autoscroll?

Answer (score 0):

hoverPause: true – pause on hover. 
this options pauses slider on mouse hover

maybe aoutoplay:  falsse ;